# dynamodb query: Can I use beginswith filter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I am trying to query a dynamodb table. When I'm using the begins with operator I'm getting the following error.

> {u'Message': u'All queries must have a condition on the hash key, and
>   it must be of type EQ', u'__type':
>   u'com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException'}

```
result_set = tb_places.query_2(
    place_name__beginswith="ame",
)
```

Here `place_name` is a Global Secondary Index

Comment: If `place_name` is the `hash_key`, a query won't work like this. You also didn't specify the index name (`index='DateJoinedIndex'`)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Regardless if you are querying a table or index, the only operator that can be applied to a Hash Key attribute is the `EQ`. Alternatively, you could use `BEGINS_WITH` on a Range Key.

> For a query on a table, you can have conditions only on the table
>   primary key attributes. You must provide the hash key attribute name
>   and value as an EQ condition. You can optionally provide a second
>   condition, referring to the range key attribute.[...]
>
> For a query on an index, you can have conditions only on the index key
>   attributes. You must provide the index hash attribute name and value
>   as an EQ condition. You can optionally provide a second condition,
>   referring to the index key range attribute.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html